# Load function by bypassing click event

Tags: jquery

I am designing a landing Page where pictures form a grid.  On clicking a button the pictures fade away and return one by one to form another rectangular grid for an interesting effect.  How can can I get it to automatically by-pass the click function and load the pictures automatically.  In other words the grid forms MINUS the user's input. (No clicking of the button which I will remove)

```
     $(".animate").on("click", function(){
     //fading out the thumbnails with style
    $("img").each(function(){
    d = Math.random()*1000; //1ms to 1000ms delay
    $(this).delay(d).animate({opacity: 0}, {
    //while the thumbnails are fading out, we will use the step function to apply some transforms. variable n will give the current opacity in the animation.
        step: function(n){
        s = 1-n; //scale - will animate from 0 to 1
        $(this).css("transform", "scale("+s+")");
        }, 
        duration: 1000, 
        })
        }).promise().done(function(){
        //after *promising* and *doing* the fadeout animation we will bring the images back
    storm();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make this run after the document has finished loading. If you would still like a delay after the page loads you would use `setTimeout()` so it runs after X seconds.

document.ready: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

setTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Either way you would want to change `$(".animate").on("click", function(){` to `$(document).ready(function(){` so it looks something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Current code here
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //Current code here
  },2000); // 2000 is 2 seconds.
});
```